# Append data frames from multiple files in a for loop

Tags: r, append

I have a script that creates a data frame from a *xlsx file. Now I would like to add a loop on top of the script that will read multiple files and append the data frames together by row. All of the column names will match. I have sample code below with what I have so far. From what I can tell, the script is reading both files but each file is writing over the previous one instead of appending to the previous. Any help would be appreciated!

```
filenames <- Sys.glob("*.xlsx")
data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")

datalist = list()

for( title in c(paste(filenames , sep="."))) {
    # ... make some data (final table named "Stats")
    df <- data.frame(Stats)
    df$title <- title    # to keep track of file  
    datalist[[title]] <- df    # add it to your list
}

big_data = do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

Comment: Why `data.files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")` if it's never used? And does `paste(filenames , sep=".")` do anything at all?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, it all seems doing as expected with some fake files (3 files).

Comment: I moved the rbind into the loop and I believe it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to append data.frames in a loop? Something like:

```
final.df <- data.frame()
for( title in c(paste(filenames , sep="."))) {
    # ... make some data (final table named "Stats")
    df <- data.frame(Stats)
    final.df <- rbind(final.df, df)
}

big_data <- final.df
```

There may be some problems with columns, but you can recognize first data frame and just substitute `final.df` with the first one.